# Absolute path import "from path import *" working but not "import path as"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-import

I just started working on a project where the import structure is something I have never seen.

Here is the structure of the package

```
 foo/
    __init__.py
    bar/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py
```

This is the content of `bar/__init__.py`:

```py
from .module1 import *
from .module2 import *
```

`module1.py` simply makes an import towards `module2` (which is empty), but using its absolute path in the project:

`from foo.bar.module2 import *`

When running code from inside the `foo` directory, I can import `module1` with no problem

```sh
python -c "import foo.bar.module1" # This will raise no error
```

However, I have been told that using `import *` from a module is bad practice (in addition to making the code really hard to read), so I decided to replace the import in `foo/bar/module1.py`by:

`import foo.bar.module2 as module2`

However, when trying my python command, I now get an `AttributeError`:

```sh
python -c "import foo.bar.module1"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/loicm/test_structure/foo/bar/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .module1 import *
  File "/Users/loicm/test_structure/foo/bar/module1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo.bar.module2 as mod
AttributeError: module 'foo' has no attribute 'bar'
```

I am quite confused since from my understanding, the different import commands would be equivalent, so that if one raises an error, the second would too

(I am aware that I can make it work without using `from ... import *` by only importing the functions that interest me instead of `*`, but it does not explain *why* it does not work)

Comment: It looks like ``module1`` is trying to use ``baz`` before it is completely imported – because that requires ``module1`` to be completely imported. Can you please try to make a simpler [mcve]? It seems like just ``bar/baz/__init__.py`` and ``bar/baz/module1.py`` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @MisterMiyagi ! I tried to remove irrelevant details from my example. Still had to keep `module2.py`as the error happens only when I try to make an import from it